# Paragraph formatting for html emails

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have 2 consecutive paragraphs in an html email. I need to have no space between the 2 paragraphs, but I need 30px of space at the top of the 1st para and at the bottom of the second paragraph.

I can remove the spaces between the 2 paragraphs using:

```
p{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
 }
```

For the space at the top & bottom of the para , I can use

```
 p{
       margin-top: 30px;
       margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

All this works fine for outlook and browsers. But when I use it for entourage (MAC email) / gmail, the space between the paragraphs is still retained.

How can I get rid of the space?

Comment: Can you use inline CSS, I mean you can do this, `<p style="padding:0;margin:0;">Content</p>`.

Comment: you can have different styles in you firs and second paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, I did use it. But this does not leave any space at the top and bottrom. How do i achieve this view + table ?

Answer (score 3):

Most web-based email clients (hotmal, gmail) will NOT honor styles defined inside a `<style>` tag simply because they just discard (almost) anything defined inside the head section. You should make your styles inline.

Answer (score 0):

These are the rare cases where using inline css make sense

this should be in your css

```
p{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
 }
```

and in your inline

```
style='margin-top: 30px;'
```

there are tricks in css to make it work but i am not sure if its supported in every browsers
you will have to google that.

example :

```
div:firstchild  p {
  ... rules..
}
```

will select the first child

Comment: This approach is not recommended for emails

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
p{background-color:green;}
div+p { margin-top:30px; }
p+p{ margin-bottom :30px; }
</style>

<div align="center"></div>
<p> first paragraph </p>
<p>Second Paragraph </p>
```

### [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/Jmnxa/2/)

**Reference :**

#### [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You can pack your paras:

```
<div>
  <p>top paragraph</p>
  <p>bottom paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And add to your CSS:

```
div
{
   padding: 30px 0;
}
```